# How do you use WebServiceMessageDrivenBean in Spring-WS?

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

How do you use the the org.springframework.ws.transport.jms.WebServiceMessageDrivenBean class from the Java Spring Framework - Spring-WS project?

There is very little documentation or examples available on the web.

Answer (score 2):

From what I gather from reading the [javadocs](http://static.springframework.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/transport/jms/WebServiceMessageDrivenBean.html) it looks like this allows a Spring [WebServiceMessageReceiver](http://static.springframework.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/transport/WebServiceMessageReceiver.html) to be invoked using a JMS client instead of a web services client.  Hopefully that's right, because the rest of this is based on that assumption.

The basics of is should match with how you create a regular Spring message driven bean.  There is a little bit of documentation on how to do that in the [Spring Reference Manual](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/ejb.html#ejb-implementation).  Also see the [AbstractEnterpriseBean Javadoc](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/ejb/support/AbstractEnterpriseBean.html?is-external=true) for some additional information about how the Spring context is retrieved.

The extra configuration required for a WebServiceMessageDrivenBean appear to be a [ConnectionFactory](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/jms/ConnectionFactory.html?is-external=true), a [WebServiceMessageFactory](http://static.springframework.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/WebServiceMessageFactory.html), and your [WebServiceMessageReceiver](http://static.springframework.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/transport/WebServiceMessageReceiver.html).  These need to use the bean names specified in the Javadoc for the WebServiceMessageDrivenBean.  The bean names are "connectionFactory", "messageFactory", and "messageReceiver" respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Using the WebServiceMessageDrivenBean is very similar to the Spring support for Message Driven Beans (MDBS).

First you create a MDB:

```
public class HelloWorldMessageDrivenBean extends WebServiceMessageDrivenBean {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2905491432314736668L;
}
```

That is it as far as the MDB goes!

Next you configure the MDB by adding the following following to the MDB definition in the  ejb-jar.xml:

```
<env-entry>  
    <description></description>  
    <env-entry-name>ejb/BeanFactoryPath</env-entry-name>  
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>  
    <env-entry-value>  
        application-context.xml  
    </env-entry-value>  
</env-entry>
```

This tells the Spring MDB support classes where to pick up your Spring configuration file.

You can now configure your endpoints either in the application-context.xml file or in addition using the annotation support.